# Buying a motorcycle for a BC to Alberta trip, when not a resident of BC

Tags: canada, legal, motorcycles, british-columbia, alberta

Not sure if this really belongs in the law Stack Exchange, but I'm gonna ask here anyway.

My friend lives in Vancouver and has suggested we take a motorcycle trip to Alberta this summer. I would fly to Vancouver, buy a motorcycle there, we would ride to Calgary, and either ride back or sell it in Alberta.

I don't know if this plan is possible, because I don't know if, *as an Ontario resident*, I can:

1. buy and register a motorcycle in BC?
2. get insurance on said motorcycle?
3. sell this motorcycle in Alberta?

I also have no idea how long these steps would take. Anyone able to shed light on this?

Comment: Can't you pay your friend to buy, register and insure the bike for you in Vancouver (under his name), and you just ride it with his permission?

Comment: This website [Buying a Car Out of Province – What You Need to Know](https://www.carfax.ca/resource-centre/articles/buying-a-car-out-of-province) is about buying a vehicle out of province.

Comment: Do you really have to register it in BC? If you intended to keep the motorbike long-term, you would probably get some temporary documents and license plates, then you would ride home to Ontario to get it properly registered in your province. I don't know the exact procedure but millions of Canadians must have already done something similar before you. In your case, you can do the same, but you will "change your mind" while in Alberta and sell it instead. Wouldn't it work?

Comment: Yeh getting him to register it seems the simplest option!

Comment: Johnnyjanko - I think to register it in Ontario I would need to go to a Service Ontario office, which are only in Ontario. Plus I definitely don't plan to ride it all the way home - it's a long way from Calgary to Ontario. And I already have far to much motorcycle in my garage.

Comment: @HarryBraviner No no, that's not what I meant. I suggested buying the motorbike in BC (telling the seller you're going to register it in Ontario), but instead of riding to Ontario and registering it there, you will sell the bike in Calgary. Would that work in Canada? In Europe it would. If you buy a vehicle abroad, you get provisional license plates, but nothing forces you to really register the vehicle properly in your home country - you sell it in another country instead.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko - I don't think that would work here. Here the plate belongs to the individual - I don't think you can easily change ownership and keep the same plates.